# Use estimation theorem to prove $|f(0)| \leq 10$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, parameter-estimation, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $f:D_2(0) -> \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and suppose that $|f(z)| \leq |z-3|^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$. Use estimation theorem to prove that $|f(0)| \leq 10$

Now I know that the estimation theorem is $|\int_{\gamma}f| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(\gamma(t)) \gamma '(t)|dt$

Following through the answer in the book:

$$|\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z}dz| \leq \int_{0}^{2\pi}|\frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)}||\gamma'(t)|dt \leq  \int_{0}^{2\pi}|\gamma(t)-3|^2$$

How does this equal the end point?

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\gamma(t)-3|^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos(t)-3)^2+\sin(t)^2dt$$

Again what identity has been used here?
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos(t)-3)^2+\sin(t)^2dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)-6\cos(t)+9)dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(10-6\cos(t))dt = [10t+6\sin(t)]_{0}^{2\pi} = 20\pi$$

Implying $|f(0)|=|\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz| \leq 10$

I can follow the last, its just the two points above I would appreciate being explained

Comment: You should tell us what $\gamma$ is before estimating an integral with it. And what does "How does this equal the end point?" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't mention the path used, in the calculation it looks as if  $\gamma(t)=e^{it}=\cos t + i \sin t$, so (using $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t =1$) we obtain $|\gamma(t)|=|\gamma'(t)|=1$ from which the inequality in the first point should be clear and for the second point we have $|\gamma(t)-3|^2 =|\cos t -3 + i \sin t |^2 = (\cos t -3 )^2+\sin^2 t$.

Comment: @Babai What are you talking about? It's a perfect answer to one of the questions.

Comment: It is intended to answer both of the two points raised. Should be understandable for someone who got across these problems but I may be wrong?

Comment: But the other question was "How does this equal the end point?" I don't think that has an answer.

Comment: Admit I made an interpretation of the not so clear question: namely how did one arrive at the last estimate (but again, my interpretation could turn out to be wrong)